# what dataprovider in flex (aside from ArrayCollection) will work for single, non-repeating XML nodes?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, dataprovider

i asked this question before but haven't been able to get an answer.. i get the following error when i retrieve an XML that only has 1 node (no repeating nodes) from a PHP page and i try to store in an ArrayCollection. -When I have MORE than 1 "name" nodes...i do NOT get an error.

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "XXXXXX" to mx.collections.ArrayCollection.
```

this error occurs as the line of code:

```
myList= e.result.list.name;
```

I'm using this ArrayCollection as a dataprovider for a Component -is there an alternative I can use that will take BOTH single and repeating nodes as well as work as a dataprovider? Thanks in advance!

code:

```
[Bindable]
private var myList:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection();

    private function getList(e:Event):void{

        var getStudyLoungesService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
        getStuffService.url = "website.com/asdf.php";
        getStuffService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onGetList);
        getStuffService.send();

    }

    private function onGetList(e:ResultEvent):void{

        myList= e.result.list.name;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLListCollection

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html

Try something like this (This is in Psuedo code):

[Bindable]
private var myList:XMLListCollection= new XMLListCollection();

```
private function getList(e:Event):void{

    var getStudyLoungesService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
    getStuffService.url = "website.com/asdf.php";
    getStuffService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onGetList);
    getStuffService.send();

}

private function onGetList(e:ResultEvent):void{
    var results : XML = e.result as XML;
    myList.source = results;
}
```

Comment: i have this as my PHP......
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><list>');
echo('<name>"name1"</name>');
echo('</list>');......and it does not work with XMLListCollection.. i get this error.....TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.collections::ArrayCollection@aaa0301 to XMLList... is there something wrong with my PHP?

Comment: That error doesn't make much sense to me.  Are you sure your PHP is sending back properly formed XML?  Have tried running the PHP results through a validator?

Comment: i think i'm getting closer flextras.. however, for the line myList.source = results; i get the following error prior to compiling...

-1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type XML to an unrelated type XMLList.  ... i have everything else exactly as you have posted.  what else can i be missing?

Comment: I'm writing psuedo code in a browser, so you'll have to excuse the fact that it isn't perfect.  XML and XMLList are different types.  You can do a cast, like this: myList.source = results as XMLListCollection and that might address it.

Comment: ok so i have made it as follows......
[Bindable]
private var myList:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection();...var results:XML = e.result.list.name as XML; ...and.....myList.source = results as XMLListCollection; however, this is still giving me an error....-1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type mx.collections:XMLListCollection to an unrelated type XMLList...i'm still not sure why.  if i change... var results:XML...to instead...var results:XMLListCollection = e.result.list.name as XMLListCollection; i still get an error.. any thoughts?